# how can i generate refresh token using laravel sanctum

Tags: laravel, api, sanctum

we know that the token must expire at some point. How can I replace an expired token with a new one in Laravel sanctum?

I haven't come up with a good idea yet

Comment: when the user login it automatically gives him new token

Comment: Yes, of course. but i have token expire after 1 day. it won't login it should automatically renew the token at login

Comment: i also search for sanctum official refresh token but they dont give us that feature. maybe this will help. https://github.com/albetnov/sanctum-refresh